# Not sure how to use jQuery noconflict function

Tags: ajax, html, prototypejs, jquery

I've been working on this site for the past two weeks and everything has been running smooth until now. I have conflicting javascripts and all though I know what method to use to solve the problem (jquery noconflict), I have no idea how to use it!

In my case, I have:

- a drop menu which uses the prototype js and a custom js
- and a contact form which uses a few jquery files for validation and error notification

The case is classic, they work fine separately but not together. Ive read a gang of websites and most point to the solution of using:

```
<script>

  jQuery.noConflict();

  // Use jQuery via jQuery(...)
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("div").hide();
  });

  // Use Prototype with $(...), etc.
  $('someid').hide();

</script>
```

Im new to javascript, so I dont know what to do with this snippet.

This is my header:

```
    <script src="js/prototype.js"></script>
    <script src="js/drop-o-matic.js"></script>
    <script>

  jQuery.noConflict();

  // Use jQuery via jQuery(...)
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("div").hide();
  });

  // Use Prototype with $(...), etc.
  $('someid').hide();

    </script> 

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>

 <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
 <![endif]-->

    <!-- <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery.jigowatt.js"></script> -->


    <script>
    document.createElement("article");  
    document.createElement("footer");  
    document.createElement("header");  
    document.createElement("hgroup");  
    document.createElement("nav");
    document.createElement("aside");
    document.createElement("section");
    document.createElement("menu");
    document.createElement("hgroup");
 </script>
```

I only have the prototype & drop-o-matic js in effect and the js files for the form is commented (just after IE comment).

The prototype & drop-o-matic are for a html5 nav (has no id's, just

```
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.php" class="home">Home</a></li>
                ...
                ...
                ...
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

What should I do to make the scripts work together?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, you are calling `jQuery.noConflict()` before you even include the jQuery library!  That definitely will not work.  You must include jQuery script tag before calling noConflict...

```
<script src="js/prototype.js"></script>
<script src="js/drop-o-matic.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script><!-- IMPORTANT -->
<script>
  jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
```

You can also give jQuery your own alias if you'd like...

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j(document).ready(function() {
  $j("div").hide();
});
```

For more information, please read the API documentation regarding [Using jQuery with Other Libraries](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries)

Answer (score 0):

One good thing you can try with jQuery is use:

```
$jq = jQuery.noConflict();
```

and then instead of using $ or jQuery right your code with

```
$jq("document").ready(function(){

// rest of your jQuery code inside;

});
```

Comment: @Gaby: Thanks, but what exactly is the jquery code I should put inside? I dont have a clue.

Comment: @gdinari, the answer belongs to @sushil (*i just formatted the code in his answer*). but to further the discussion, are you sure you have included the jquery framework in your code ? in your example code it seems like it is in comments and after the no conflict part.. Have a look at @josh answer

Comment: I commented the jquery because it wasn't working with nav bar scripts. I'll look into Josh's answer, it seems like the better approach. Thanks a mil